# How to check whether all columns in a row are positive numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a new column by comparing two boolean columns. If both are positive, I assign a 1, otherwise a 0. This is my code below, but is there a way to be more pythonic? I tried list comprehension but failed.

```
lst = []
for i,k in zip(df['new_customer'],df['y']):
    if i == 1 & k == 1:
        lst.append(1)
    else:
        lst.append(0) 
df['new_customer_subscription'] = lst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.sign`:

```
m = np.sign(df[['new_customer', 'y']]) >= 0
df['new_customer_subscription'] = m.all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

If you want to consider only positive non-zero values, change `>= 0` to `> 0` (since `np.sign(0)` is 0).

```
# Sample DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df

          A         B
0  0.511684 -0.512633
1 -1.254813 -1.721734
2  0.751830  0.285449
3 -0.934877  1.407998
4 -1.686066 -0.947015

# Get the sign of the numbers.
m = np.sign(df[['A', 'B']]) >= 0
m

       A      B
0   True  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
3  False   True
4  False  False

# Find all rows where both columns are `True`.
m.all(axis=1).astype(int)

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
dtype: int64
```

---

Another solution if you have to deal with only two columns would be:

```
df['new_customer_subscription'] = (
    df['new_customer'].gt(0) & df['y'].gt(0)).astype(int)
```

To generalise to multiple columns, use `logical_and.reduce`:

```
df['new_customer_subscription'] =  np.logical_and.reduce(
    df[['new_customer', 'y']] > 0, axis=1).astype(int)
```

Or,

```
df['new_customer_subscription'] = (df[['new_customer', 'y']] > 0).all(1).astype(int)
```

Comment: what's the purpose of the second line? Thanks!

Comment: @Odisseo added explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: My apologies, my python has been running for over an hour but as soon as it's done I will test and definitely provide feedback. Sorry for the wait

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is using the `np.where` from the `numpys` module:

```
df['Indicator'] = np.where((df.A > 0) & (df.B > 0), 1, 0)
```

**Output**

```
    A           B           Indicator
0   -0.464992   0.418243    0
1   -0.902320   0.496530    0
2   0.219111    1.052536    1
3   -1.377076   0.207964    0
4   1.051078    2.041550    1
```

The `np.where` method works like this:

```
np.where(condition, true value, false value)
```

Comment: Which is OK, but does not generalise easily to multiple columns.